How to blur certain portions of a latex pdf document?
I need to send my master's thesis to one admission committee for admission purposes. But my thesis contain some important results that we don't want to share before publishing it as a paper. Is there a way to blur those sections or pages in LateX or Overleaf? I want to show first few pages of the thesis unblurred and blur rest of the document.

are you sending the pdf? in which case "blurring" is not enough as the text is still there (eg for cut and paste) you need to actually redact the text, tools such as acrobat can do that, If you are sending paper then that is not an issue of course.

As I understood You want to hide a part of your text (or even images) but leave blank space instead of them, right?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\hide#1{{\color{white}#1}}

\newsavebox\abimagebox
\DeclareDocumentCommand \includegraphicsd { o m }{%
    \sbox\abimagebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[draw, dashed, text width=\the\wd\abimagebox,minimum height=\the\ht\abimagebox, align=center, inner sep=0]{This is a hidden image};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

%This image is shown
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.345\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Very nice caption}
\end{figure}

%This one is not shown
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphicsd[width=0.345\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Very nice caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\noindent
\phantom{%%% remove to make visible
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}%
}%%% remove to make visible

\lipsum[4]
\end{document} 


It may look as if it is obscured, but the stuff is all still in the PDF. If the information is not supposed to be released until later publication, I doubt this is good enough. If it was good enough, you could just ask the committee to keep the contents confidential.

Is it possible to add a layer of blur on the original document, such that the reader can see there is some content hidden, but can not read or comprehend it?

@Igris I have not found something like Glassmorphism effect in latex, unfortunatelly, but somebody skilled in tikz (I suppose) can help you, may be...

I'm wondering if a package that enables redaction of documents would suffice. I'm thinking of https://ctan.org/pkg/srcredact, https://ctan.org/pkg/censor, or https://ctan.org/pkg/luacensor.
